# A question on Dirac delta function

Tags: notation, calculus, dirac-delta-distributions

If

$$\int f(x)\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\delta(x-x’)\mathrm{d}x=-f’(x’)$$

What happens when I switch the integration and differentiation to $x’$ instead of $x$? Will I just get the negated result of the above RHS?

Comment: It's simple enough to work it out explicitly, using a substitution of variables... What are you having trouble with?

Comment: I’m kind of confused as to how to do the substitution of variables. If I let $x=-x’$, then I will get an overall minus sign which will negate the RHS of the equation in the post. Is this correct?

Comment: Not at all! If you set $x = -x'$, then the right hand side would be $-f'(-x)$, which is certainly not $f'(x)$, unless $f$ is an odd function! I'm not really sure what you want to calculate, is it: $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x'} \delta(x-x')\text{d}x',$$ or is it $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x') \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x'} \delta(x-x')\text{d}x'?$$ The latter is trivial, since you can just interchange $x\leftrightarrow x'$ and you'd get back your original integral, and the former is trivial because $f(x)$ would just be a constant and can be taken out of the integral.

Comment: I was looking for the latter case. Thanks for the clarification! Confused myself there.